# If $(a,b,c)$ are the sides of a triangle, what is the probability that $ac>b^2$?

Tags: probability, geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-probability

Let $a \le b \le c$ be the sides of a triangle inscribed inside a fixed circle such that the vertices of the triangle are distributed uniformly on the circumference.

**Question 1**: Is it true that the probability that $ac > b^2$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{5}$. I ran a simulation by generating $1.75 \times 10^9$ triangle and counting the number of times $ac > b^2$. The experimental data seems to suggest that probability converges to about $0.2$.

**Note**: For any triangle with $a \le b \le c$, the triangle inequality implies $b < a+c < 3b$. Now the condition $ac > b^2$ implies that $2b < a+c < 3b$; here the lower bound follows from AM-GM inequality. Hence all triangles for which $b < a+c < 2b$ are ruled out. For our problem, the condition $2b < a+c < 3b$ is necessary but not sufficient.

**Update**: Changed the title in light of the comments and answer that relaxing the condition $a\le b \le c$ is easier to handle

[image]

Related question: [If $(a,b,c)$ are the sides of a triangle and $x \ge 1$, what is the probability that $a+b > cx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840303/if-a-b-c-are-the-sides-of-a-triangle-and-x-ge-1-what-is-the-probability)

Comment: Hint: the distance between two points on the unit circle is $2|\sin((\theta- \theta')/2)|$

Comment: The difficult thing about this problem is converting "the vertices of the triangle are distributed uniformly on the circumference" into an integral of continuous functions without losing the correct distribution.  You might see different plausible solutions with different results because of this is very hard to get right.

Comment: You have to have a probabilistic assumption to have a (non trivial) probabilistic conclusion.

Comment: Can you start by $a+b \ge c$?

Comment: Note that if we don't order the side lengths, $ac\gt b^2$ will never be fulfilled if $b$ is the longest side and will always be fulfilled if $b$ is the shortest side, so the probability $\frac15$ in the ordered case is equivalent to the probability

$$
\frac13\left(0+\frac15+1\right)=\frac25
$$

in the unordered case. That might be a bit easier to deal with.

Comment: See https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-geo-dft and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assume that the circle is the unit circle centred at the origin, and the vertices of the triangle are:
$A(\cos(-Y),\sin(-Y))$ where $0\le Y\le2\pi$
$B(1,0)$
$C(\cos X,\sin X)$ where $0\le X\le2\pi$

*Relax the requirement* that $a \le b \le c$, and let:
$a=BC=2\sin\left(\frac{X}{2}\right)$
$b=AC=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi-X-Y}{2}\right)\right|=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)\right|$
$c=AB=2\sin\left(\frac{Y}{2}\right)$

$\therefore P[ac>b^2]=P\left[\sin\left(\frac{X}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{Y}{2}\right)>\sin^2\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)\right]$ where $0\le X\le2\pi$ and $0\le Y\le2\pi$

This probability is the ratio of the area of the shaded region to the area of the square in the graph below.

[image]

Rotate these regions $45^\circ$ clockwise about the origin, then shrink by factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, then translate left $\pi$ units, by letting $X=x+\pi-y$ and $Y=x+\pi+y$.

[image]

$\begin{align}
P[ac>b^2]&=P\left[\sin\left(\frac{x+\pi-y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x+\pi+y}{2}\right)>\sin^2(x+\pi)\right]\\
&=P\left[\cos(x+\pi)-\cos y<-2\sin^2(x+\pi)\right]\text{ using sum to product identity}\\
&=P\left[-\cos x-\cos y<-2\sin^2 x\right]\\
&=P\left[-\arccos(2\sin^2x-\cos x)<y<\arccos(2\sin^2x-\cos x)\right]\\
&=\dfrac{\int_0^{\pi/3}\arccos(2\sin^2x-\cos x)\mathrm dx}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}
\end{align}$

[Numerical evidence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Divide%5B5%2CPower%5Bpi%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29Integrate%5Barccos%5C%2840%292Power%5B%5C%2840%29sinx%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-cosx%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CDivide%5Bpi%2C3%5D%7D%5D) suggests that the integral equals $\frac{\pi^2}{5}$. (I've posted this integral as [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838494/398708).) If that's true, then the probability is $\frac25$.

If the probability *without* requiring $a \le b \le c$ is $\frac25$ , it follows that the probability *with* requiring $a \le b \le c$ is $\frac15$, as @joriki explained in the comments.

### Update:

The integral has been [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4838976/398708) to equal $\frac{\pi^2}{5}$, thus showing that the answer to the OP is indeed $1/5$.

The simplicity of the answer, $1/5$, suggests that there might be a more intuitive solution, but given the amount of attention the OP has received, an intuitive solution seems to be quite elusive. We might have to chalk this one up as another probability question with a simple answer but no intuitive explanation. (Other examples of such probability questions are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4803481/398708) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4799757/398708).)

Comment: Hi Dan, I was thinking about writing a paper on various geometrical probabilities that I have posted in the site. You have answered few of them. I would like to include  your solution and give due to credits to you. Let me know.

Answer (score 12):

This is not an answer, rather a numerical exploration. We may suppose that the three points are on the unit circle and that one of them is $P=(1, 0)$. Let the two other points be $Q = (\cos x, \sin x)$ and $R=(\cos y, \sin y)$. Let us define the set
\begin{equation}
S = \{(x, y) | \min(a,b,c)\max(a,b,c)> \text{mid}(a,b,c)^2\}
\end{equation}
where $a = 2 |\sin(x/2)|$, $b = 2|\sin(y/2)|$, $c = 2|\sin((x-y)/2)|$ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle.

I was able to plot the indicator function ${\bf 1}_S(x,y)$ in [image]The picture of ${\bf 1}_S(x+\frac{y}{2},y)$ shows even more regularity. It seems that only a few sine-like curves are involved in this picture [image]

Edit: I updated the pictures. The original version of this post inverted the $x$ and $y$ axis.

Using @joriki 's comment that the problem is equivalent to showing that the probability of the unordered triple $(a, b, c)$ satisfies $a c > b^2$ is $2/5$ allows us to create a simpler picture. Let
\begin{equation}
U = \{(x, y) | a c> b^2\}
\end{equation}
with the same definition of $a, b, c$. Plotting the function ${\bf 1}_U(x+\frac{y}{2},y)$ gives the much simpler picture [image]

The sine-looking function appearing in this picture can be proved to have the equation
\begin{equation}
y = 2 \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{17 +  8\cos x}\right)
\end{equation}
for $0\le x\le \pi$. So the question reduces to: **Is is true that**
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{17 +  8\cos x}\right) d x = \frac{2}{5}
\end{equation}
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%282%2Fpi%5E2%29*%20arccos%28%28-1%20%2B%20sqrt%2817%20%2B%208*%20cos%28x%29%29%29%2F4%29%20from%200%20to%20pi) actually gives this value numerically.
Here is how the equation of the curve can be established, recall that $2 \sin  u \sin  v = \cos  \left(u-v\right)-\cos  \left(u+v\right)$, then

\begin{equation}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{rl}&\sin  \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{4}\right) \sin  \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{4}\right) = {\sin }^{2} \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\displaystyle  \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos  \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-\cos  \left(x\right)\right) = {\sin }^{2} \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\displaystyle  {\cos }^{2} \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \cos  \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-\left(1+\frac{\cos  \left(x\right)}{2}\right) = 0\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\displaystyle  \cos  \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) =-\frac{1}{4} \pm  \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{17+8 \cos  \left(x\right)}\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\displaystyle  \cos  \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) =-\frac{1}{4} +  \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{17+8 \cos  \left(x\right)}
\end{array}\end{equation}

Answer (score 10):

Let $0\lt x\le y\le z\lt\pi$ be the three half-angles of the triangle, with $x+y+z=\pi$. Then with the comment by @Gribouillis the condition $ac\gt b^2$ translates to

$$
\sin x\sin z\gt\sin^2y
$$

and thus, with $\sin z=\sin(\pi-x-y)=\sin(x+y)$, to

$$
\sin x\sin(x+y)\gt\sin^2 y\;.
$$

Applying the addition theorem yields

$$
\sin x(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)\gt\sin^2y\;.
$$

To solve for $x$, isolate $\cos x$,

$$
\cos x\gt\frac{\sin y}{\sin x}-\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}\cos y\;,
$$

square,

$$
\cos^2 x\gt\frac{\sin^2 y}{\sin^2 x}+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin^2 y}\cos^2y-2\cos y\;,
$$

use $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $\sin^2y+\cos^2y=1$ and simplify:

$$
1+2\cos y\gt\frac{\sin^2 y}{\sin^2 x}+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin^2 y}\;.
$$

This is a quadratic inequality for $\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin^2 y}$, and the relevant solution branch in our case is

$$
\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin^2 y}\gt\frac12+\cos y-\sqrt{\left(\frac12+\cos y\right)^2-1}\;.
$$

Thus the bound for $x$ as a function of $y$ is

$$
x\gt f(y):=\arcsin\left(\sin y\sqrt{\frac12+\cos y-\sqrt{\left(\frac12+\cos y\right)^2-1}}\right)\;.
$$

The range for $x$ is $0\lt x\le y$ if $y\le\frac\pi3$ and $0\lt x\le1-2y$ if $\frac\pi3\le y\lt\frac\pi2$. In the latter case, we never have $ac\gt b^2$, so the desired probability is

\begin{eqnarray*}
1-\frac{\int_0^\frac\pi3f(y)\mathrm dy+\int_\frac\pi3^\frac\pi2(1-2y)\mathrm dy}{\int_0^\frac\pi3y\mathrm dy+\int_\frac\pi3^\frac\pi2(1-2y)\mathrm dy}
&=&
1-\frac{\int_0^\frac\pi3f(y)\mathrm dy+\frac{\pi^2}{36}}{\frac{\pi^2}{18}+\frac{\pi^2}{36}}
\\
&=&\frac23-\frac{12}{\pi^2}\int_0^\frac\pi3f(y)\mathrm dy\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

This is $\frac15$ if we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\frac\pi3f(y)\mathrm dy
&=&
\frac7{180}\pi^2
\\
&\approx&
0.383817948931253\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

and indeed this is what a [numerical Wolfram|Alpha integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NIntegrate%20%5Barcsin%28%28sin%20%28x%29%20*%20sqrt%20%28%281%20%2B%202%20*%20cos%20x%29%2F2%20-%20sqrt%28%28%281%2B2cos%20x%29%2F2%29%5E2-1%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cpi%2F3%7D%2CWorkingPrecision-%3E15%5D) to $15$ decimal places yields.

I haven’t been able to solve the integral analytically, but in any case, this is a very inelegant approach – a simple result like $\frac15$ for a geometric probability usually has a nice explanation based on symmetry. I was hoping that perhaps one could show that exactly $2$ of the $10$ triangles formed by $5$ points fulfil the condition, but this is far from the case; that number varies between $0$ and $5$. Still, I wouldn’t be surprised if someone comes up with an elegant solution.

Comment: Although you say this is not elegant, this almost does the job provided the integral is proved. As a by product, we have a complex looking integral with suspected closed form which could be of interest to the integration experts in MSE. Also note that $ac > b^2$ implies $a+b > 2b$. Not sure if this formulation would help coming up with a simpler integral without the square root.

Comment: @Joriki why not use discriminant?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-probability-of-complex-roots-assuming-that-the-coefficients-of-the-quadratic-ax-2-bx-c-are-selected-from-the-uniform-distribution-on-2-2

Comment: @DesmosTutu: How do you propose to use the discriminant?

Comment: @NilotpalSinha: $a+b\gt2b$ is equivalent to $a\gt b$, which contradicts $a\le b$. Was there a typo there?

Comment: Yes typo indeed. It is $2b<a+c<3b$. Pls see my updated note in the original post.

Comment: @Joriki see the link.

Comment: @DesmosTutu: I did follow your link. There's nothing about triangles there. I don't see how you propose to relate that problem to this one.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha: You rightly write that that condition is necessary but not sufficient. (The probability for it to be fulfilled is about $0.253$.) We'd still have to calculate the probability of the difference of those two events, and the boundary of that difference includes at least a part of the boundary of the event of interest, so I don't think much is gained by that.

Comment: I don't think the probability density for selection of the three points is uniform in your $xy$-plane.

Comment: @Joriki https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125013/triangle-in-parabola

Comment: @DesmosTutu: I would much appreciate it if you'd explain in clear terms what you propose to do rather than just posting links whose relevance isn't immediately apparent.

Comment: I propose to connect the inequality in terms of envelope (see example 2 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics) ) and then use the properties of kiepert parabola .I refresh the problem I don't solve it.

Comment: @DesmosTutu: I give up. I can't see the relevance of any of that.

Comment: @Joriki OK. Let the the idea goes .

Answer (score 4):

Let the fixed circle be of unit radius and center $(0,0)$ and define the vertices of the triangle as:
$$
B=(1,0),\quad C=(\cos\gamma,\sin\gamma),\quad A=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha),
$$
where $\gamma=\angle BOC <\alpha =\angle BOA$. Define as usual:
$$
a=BC,\quad b=AC,\quad c=AB.
$$
The condition $b\ge a$ is equivalent to ${1\over2}(\alpha-\gamma)\ge{1\over2}\gamma$, that is: $\alpha\ge2\gamma$.
The condition $c\ge b$ is equivalent to $\pi-{1\over2}\alpha\ge{1\over2}(\alpha-\gamma)$, that is: $\alpha\le\pi+{1\over2}\gamma$. These inequalities can be rewritten as:
$$
0\le\gamma\le{2\over3}\pi,\quad 2\gamma\le\alpha\le\pi+{1\over2}\gamma.
$$
The condition $ac>b^2$ can be written as
$$
\sin{\alpha\over2}\sin{\gamma\over2}>\sin^2{\alpha-\gamma\over2}
$$
but explicitating from that some bounds for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ is very difficult.
Anyway, the requested probability $p$ can be computed from:
$$
p={\int_0^{2\pi/3}\int_{2\gamma}^{\pi+\gamma/2}I(\alpha,\gamma)\,d\alpha 
d\gamma
\over
\int_0^{2\pi/3}\int_{2\gamma}^{\pi+\gamma/2}d\alpha 
d\gamma},
$$
where
$$
I(\alpha,\gamma)=\cases{
1 & if $\sin{\alpha\over2}\sin{\gamma\over2}>\sin^2{\alpha-\gamma\over2}$\\
0 & otherwise
}
$$
I computed that numerically and got $p\approx0.20000$, with Mathematica complaining that the estimate of the error was $\approx0.00004$. Playing with the options in Mathematica, or using some other tool, might lead to more accurate results.

Answer (score -1):

$a = b - x$
$c = b + y$

$ac = (b - x)(b + y) = b^2 - [(x - y)b + xy]$

For $ac > b^2$, it must be that
$(x - y)b + xy < 0$
$(x - y)b < - xy$
$(y - x)b > xy$
$by - xy > bx$
$f(x) = y > \frac{bx}{b - x}$

For some value of $b$, we get the ordered pair $(x, y)$ and with that we get the set $A$ consisting of points $(a, b, c)$ such that $ac > b^2$.

We need to do something similar for $ac \leq b^2$. Again we should get a solution set $B$, consisting of points $(a, b, c)$ such that $ac \leq b^2$.

Note, the domain is/has to be restricted to $(a, b, c)$ where $a, b, c$ are lengths of the sides of a triangle.

Then $P(ac > b^2) = \frac{n(A)}{n(A) + n(B)}$

We should actually be working with *area*, considering the continuous nature of $a, b, c$, but I don't know how to.

P. S. $B = A^c$

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question?

Answer (score -1):

Too long for a comment :

The problem of the order fixing the value of the probability can be solved using the concept of duality ( the dual of a triangle is also a triangle)

Next we have a useful formula see the wiki page [Crofton formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula)

I quote a part of it :

$S_1$,$S_2$, with $S_{1}$ nested inside
$S_{2}$, the probability of a random line
$l$ intersecting the inner surface
$S_{1}$,conditional on it intersecting the outer surface
, is...

End of the quote

So in this case we start by the integral defining the probability in term of area and to conclude we use the condition $ac>b^2$

Further explanation :

If we take two triangle one in another the probability that a line intersecting the two triangle (given above) is equivalent to says excluding the homothetic case that one of the side is sufficiently large and so there is a constraint on it or here $ac>b^2$