# If $(a,b,c)$ are the sides of a triangle and $x \ge 1$, what is the probability that $a+b > cx$?

Tags: probability, integration, geometry, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to generalize the triangle inequality in probabilistic terms. Assume that the vertices are uniformly distributed around the circumference of a fixed circle. [In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836901/if-a-b-c-are-the-sides-of-a-triangle-what-is-the-probability-that-acb2) it was proved that if $(a,b,c)$ are the sides of a triangle than the probability that geometric mean of any two sides is greater than the third side i.e. $P\left(\sqrt{ab} > c\right) = \frac{2}{5}$. Since $a+b > 2\sqrt{ab}$, it implies that probability that $P(a+b > 2c) > \frac{2}{5}$. In general, we can ask:

**Question**: If $(a,b,c)$ are the sides of a triangle and $x \ge 1$, what is the probability that $a+b > cx$?

**Experimental data**: For each $x$ between $1$ and $300$ and at intervals of $0.01$, I ran $10^7$ trails and obtained an estimate of the complimentary cumulative distribution function $P(a+b > cx)$ plotted below.

[image]

Intuitively the graph makes sense since for $x=1$ the standard triangle inequality implies that the probability is $1$; and as $x \to \infty$ the probability must approach $0$ since we can make the sides $a$ and $b$ arbitrarily large and $c$ arbitrarily small. On fitting different models to this data, the best fit with an $R^2$ value of $0.999996$ and a standard error of $0.00019$ was given by

$$
P(a+b > cx) = \frac{6}{5x+1}
$$

**Update** 9-Jan-2024: In my code, I was sorting the angles before getting the side length due to which order of the side cannot be interchanged. Under this restricted conditions, the above model could be the probability, however in unconditional case were the sides can be interchanged and vertices are uniformly distributed, the answer by @Empy2 is correct.

**Equivalence with the Basel's Problem**: The series in the accepted answer is actually the [Lengendre Chi function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresChi-Function.html) $\chi_2\left(\frac1{x}\right)$. Taking
$x = 1$ and applying the fact that the sum of the reciprocal of odd squares is $3/4$-th the sum over the reciprocal of the squares of natural numbers we find that the probability that the sum of any two sides of a triangle is greater than than the third side is $\displaystyle \frac{6\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}$. Since this probability must be $1$ and the proof does not require the value of  to be known in advance, it unexpectedly implies that:

> *The triangle inequality equivalent to*  $$ 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} +
> \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

I have changed the title to reflect this remarkable connection.

**Related question**: [If $(a,b,c)$ are the sides of a triangle, is it true that probability that $a+b > c^{\frac{3}{c}}$ is $\zeta(2)-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877203/if-a-b-c-are-the-sides-of-a-triangle-is-it-true-that-probability-that-ab)

Comment: If you plot $1/P$, what does the graph look like?

Comment: @Empy2 It like looks a perfect straight line so it is consistent with $\frac{6}{5x+1}$. I have added the plot in the post. I am unable to understand why a model who area under curve $> 1$ fits this data so perfectly.

Comment: What you found is not a pdf. It is the complementary function of the random variable $X=\frac{a+b}{c}$, that is, $\bar{F}_X(x)=1-F_X(x)$, with $F_X(x)$ denoting the cdf of $X$, so the area under the curve can be larger than 1.

Comment: @Amir You are right. It was an oversight form me. So $\frac{6}{5x+1}$ may indeed the right equation. I will update this in the post.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html see Ex.kurtosis

Comment: It is better to focus on the first problem in the title; the new title is not suitable for a question ( you can add a short subtitle).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a formula for the probability, which for large $x$ is roughly $$\frac4{\pi^2}(\frac2x+\frac2{9x^3}+\frac2{25x^5}+\cdots)$$
The series continues in the same form up to at least the $x^{-11}$ term.  There is an integral form at the end of this answer.

Solution:

The angles in the triangle are all twice the corresponding angles at the centre of the circle.  So the trio of angles $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is equally distributed over the flat region in 3space with vertices $(\pi,0, 0),(0,\pi,0),(0,0,\pi)$.
The area of a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ is $$\Delta=\frac12ab\sin\gamma=\frac12ca\sin\beta=\frac12bc\sin\alpha$$
So for example $a=\frac{abc}{2\Delta}\sin\alpha$, and the ratio we want is $$\frac{a+b}c=\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\sin\gamma}\\=\frac{2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\\
=\frac{\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2}{\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2}$$
The region of interest is $0\le\alpha,0\le \beta,\alpha+\beta\le\pi$.  Change variables to $$\theta=\frac{\alpha+\beta}2,\phi=\frac{\alpha-\beta}2$$
The region is now $$0\le\theta\le\pi/2,\\-\theta\le\phi\le\theta$$ with area $\pi^2/4$.
The ratio of interest is greater than $x$ when $$\cos\theta\lt\frac{\cos\phi}x$$
For a given $\phi$, Theta ranges over an interval of length
$$\pi/2-\arccos(\frac{\cos\phi}x)\\=\arcsin(\frac{\cos\phi}x)$$
Integrate that over the region to give $$\frac4{\pi^2}\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\arcsin(\frac{\cos\phi}x)d\phi$$
I used a series expansion in arcsine $x+\frac{x^3}6+\frac{3x^5}{40}+\cdots$ to get the series at the top.

Comment: Could you find a closed form fromula for the pdf by derivating with respect to $x$?

Comment: @Amir Wolfram says it is $\frac8{\pi^2}\tanh^{-1}(1/x)/x$

Comment: @Empy2 When you say large $x$, how large will $x$ have to be for this formula to give an estimate of $P(a+b>cx)$ ?

Comment: The limit as $x\to1$ is $1$, as hoped, so perhaps it works for all $x\ge1$

Comment: Are the denominator's the squares of odd natural numbers of the first few terms are a co-incidence? If they are indeed the odd squares then identities involving $\zeta(2)$ show the at $x=1$, the sum of the series is exactly $1$ as expected.

Comment: Also since the empirical model in the post fits the data extremely well, it shows that $\frac{6}{5x+1}$ must be a very good estimate of $\frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2 x^{2k-1}}$.

Comment: So it implies the famous triangle inequality $a+b>c$ is equivalent to the Euler's famous Basel problem $1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Wow !!!!

Comment: @NilotpalSinha  You may inculde a plot of both for a comparison.

Comment: The series expansion for arcsin works when the input is in $[-1,1]$, so in our case as long as $x\ge 1$. So what's to stop this answer from working for all $x$? Is there a subtlety with the convergence to look out for?

Comment: However, inputting some numbers, this result doesn't seem to match very well at all with the linear graph ($1/P(x)$) in the question...

Comment: @Empy2 The series is actually the Legendre Chi function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function

Comment: @Empy2 Hi, I am thinking about a short paper highlighting the equivalence of the famous Basel problem and the basic triangle inequality (plus other things connecting number theory with triangles). Your solution is the main ingredient for the first part. I would like to include your proof and give you full credits for it. Let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha That's fine, there are no issues I know of.

Answer (score 6):

The posted code is wrong. I've refactored/bugfixed it slightly and the asymptotic value is in fact $8 / \pi^2$. The issue with sorting angles is that $a$ will be too small compared to $c$ (compared to if $a, b, c$ were generated from uniformly selected points and not ordered themselves).

```
from math import pi

import numpy as np

k = 2 * np.pi
n = 10**5
x = 1.0
max = 50
inc = 0.5

# just run n trials for each value of x instead
while x < max:
    success = 0
    for _ in range(1, n):
        # remove the sort
        angles = np.random.uniform(0, k, 3)
        
        vertices_x = np.cos(angles)
        vertices_y = np.sin(angles)
        
        vertices_x = np.append(vertices_x, vertices_x[0])
        vertices_y = np.append(vertices_y, vertices_y[0])
        
        x_diff = np.diff(vertices_x)
        y_diff = np.diff(vertices_y)
        side_lengths = np.sqrt(x_diff ** 2 + y_diff ** 2)
        
        a = side_lengths[0]
        b = side_lengths[1]
        c = side_lengths[2]

        if a + b > x * c:
            success += 1
    
    print(f'x: {x:.4f}'[:-1], f'x * P(x): {x * success / n:.10f}'[:-1], f'8/pi^2: {8 / pi ** 2}')

    x += 0.5
```

Sample output:

````
x: 1.000 x * P(x): 0.999990000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 1.500 x * P(x): 0.861450000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 2.000 x * P(x): 0.830600000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 2.500 x * P(x): 0.830900000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 3.000 x * P(x): 0.825840000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 3.500 x * P(x): 0.817775000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 4.000 x * P(x): 0.818160000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 4.500 x * P(x): 0.814860000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 5.000 x * P(x): 0.818700000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 5.500 x * P(x): 0.818895000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 6.000 x * P(x): 0.804540000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 6.500 x * P(x): 0.800540000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 7.000 x * P(x): 0.809200000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 7.500 x * P(x): 0.809550000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 8.000 x * P(x): 0.808240000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 8.500 x * P(x): 0.808520000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 9.000 x * P(x): 0.815310000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 9.500 x * P(x): 0.797240000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 10.000 x * P(x): 0.815900000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 10.500 x * P(x): 0.802200000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 11.000 x * P(x): 0.827090000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 11.500 x * P(x): 0.813280000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 12.000 x * P(x): 0.818640000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 12.500 x * P(x): 0.813875000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 13.000 x * P(x): 0.815750000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 13.500 x * P(x): 0.806895000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 14.000 x * P(x): 0.832300000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 14.500 x * P(x): 0.802865000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 15.000 x * P(x): 0.823050000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 15.500 x * P(x): 0.805225000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 16.000 x * P(x): 0.816480000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 16.500 x * P(x): 0.805035000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
x: 17.000 x * P(x): 0.801380000 8/pi^2: 0.8105694691387022
```
````

Comment: Well that settles it. Thanks !!

Answer (score -2):

I make a connection with a famous problem the disk triangle picking see

[Dtp](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskTrianglePicking.html)

[image: dtp]

Note that the probability decrease as the graph of the Op .

Comment: Why a downvote ?

Comment: The graph in this question shows $P(a+b > cx)$ as a function of $x$. The graph in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskTrianglePicking.html shows $P(A)$ as a function of $A$. Can you elaborate how these problems are connected? Or do the graphs just look similar by coincidence?

Comment: Dear Martin ask you which as follow : what is independent in $a+b>cx$ ? How write area in term of side ? What's give a bit of algebra ?